# Angular2 e2e test case with protractor throwing error

Tags: sockets, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have created my app with [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and i have used [socket.io](http://socket.io) with it. I have created one common service to create socket connection and listen its method. this service is used and initialized after user is logged in. When app is running and i execute test case for login, i am checking url with below code :

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then((url) => {
    expect(url).toEqual('/dashboard');    
});
```

The issue is when socket is connected its throwing error 'Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 15 seconds' and if socket is not connected same test case is running without any error.

Comment: Have you tried `expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('/dashboard');`?

Comment: This is error is not only for `browser.getCurrentUrl()` but this error is coming for my all test cases also where i have used some different `expect` condition for different selectors. All test case is working before when socket is not implemented but after adding socket its stops working.

Comment: I'll bet there is something out of sync with the way you are implementing the socket in your test and protractor's control flow. Do you mind updating your post with the relevant test code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if connecting to the socket is actually make things take longer or not but if the 15 seconds isn't enough time, you can change the 
`allScriptsTimeout:timeout_in_millis` in your protractor configuration file

[protractor timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)

Comment: I have already tried it but it didn't work. what i think is issue is because socket connection is remain  open after connection to server is done and protractor is waiting to complete that process by closing the connection.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue and I agree with you that it must be websockets. We are opening a websocket and are waiting with an observable.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I have found is:

> (This is copied from here for your convenience.  All credit goes to https://github.com/cpa-level-it
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11853#issuecomment-277185526)

What I did to fix the problem was using ngZone everywhere I have an observable that relies on socket.io.

So let's say you have this method in your service that gives you an observable on a socket.io.

```
private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

 public getSocketIOEvents(): Observable<SocketIOEvent> {

        if (this.socket == null) {
            this.socket = io.connect(this._socketPath);
        }

        return Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            this.socket.on('eventA', (item: any) => observer.next(new SocketIOEvent(item)));
            this.socket.on('eventB', (item: any) => observer.next(new SocketIOEvent(item)));
            return () => this.socket.close();
        });
    }
```

Then you need to use the ngZone service to tell Angular to create the socket outside the Angular 2 zone and then execute the callback of the Observable inside the Angular 2 zone.

```
import {  NgZone } from '@angular/core';
constructor(
    private socketService: SocketIOService,    ,
    private ngZone: NgZone) { }


ngOnInit() {

    // Subscribe to the Observable outside Angular zone...    
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.socketService
        .getSocketIOEvents()
        .subscribe(event => {

         // Come back into Angular zone when there is a callback from the Observable
           this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.handleEvent(event);
          });
        });
    });

  }
```

This way protractor doesn't hang waiting on the socket.