# Running e2e test using protractor with Angular2 and Socket.io

Tags: angular, socket.io, protractor

I got configured `protractor` that runs my `e2e` tests. But since I've added a `socket.io` to my application and call `io.connect` protractor returns error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds.

How can I test Angular 2 app with real backend using protractor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 e2e test case with protractor throwing error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930272/angular2-e2e-test-case-with-protractor-throwing-error)

Answer (score 1):

I also stumpled over this problem and opened an issue in the angular-repo: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11853